# Drupal and cache in node_load

Tags: caching, nodes

I have written a simple module for counting node views. For each nid I store 2 numbers: impression and view.

1 Impression is when the node is loaded and visualized in any display mode (teaser, views ecc..) so when I open a taxonomy term page, every nid listed gets a +1 Impression. Or, for example, I have a view that loads some nodes displaing only its main_image fields: i want a +1 impression for every one of these.

1 view is when the node is viewed in full mode, so when is opened /node/12, nid 12 gets a +1 view.

This behavior is made simply in my module counter:

```
// hook for impressions
function counter_node_load($nodes, $types) {
    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
        // store in db +1 impression for $node->nid
    }
}

// hook for views
function counter_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
    if ($view_mode == 'full') {
        // store in db +1 view for $node->nid
    }
}
```

that's it.

It will be awsome if this works with drupal cache enabled, but it doesn't. Probably because drupal cache stores the html of the page/block and the node_load, node_view isn't called anymore. 
What can I do to achieve the same result explained above (impressions, views) with cache enabled?

Comment: You'll need to track it using the frontend (1px image or JavaScript), similar to how GA is used https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/concepts/gaConceptsTrackingOverview.

Comment: How I track a single node_load?